# Words for three or four nights before

Tags: word-request

One nights before = last night.

What is common word for 2, 3, or 4 nights before?

What about 1, 2, or 3 nights after tonight?

Comment: "the night before last" is two nights ago. Beyond that you could use "a few nights ago", but if you need to be specific use the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically use phrases to describe when a night or day occurs relative to the current one. I think I can see that you already know a few of them.

Common ones for nights before:

- Two nights past, I ate cereal... (two nights before tonight)
- A few nights ago, I ate cereal... (three nights before tonight)
- It's been four nights since I ate cereal... (four nights before tonight)

Common ones for nights after:

- Tomorrow night, I will eat cereal... (one night after tonight)
- Night after next, I will eat cereal... (two nights after tonight)
- A few nights from now, I will eat cereal... (three nights after tonight)

Comment: In Persian we have phrases up to 4 nights past. Dishab, Parishab, Pasparishab, Pasan pas parishab.